# timepicker floating not in box

Tags: jquery

i am trying to add timepicker on to my page. problem is it is not displayed in box only floating writing on the page. Can some please help explain how to fix this issue i have uploaded an image. for browser web app

```
<div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="appt-time">Choose an appointment time: </label>
                    <input id="durationExample" type="text" class="time" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                            <script>
                                $(function() {
                                    $('#durationExample').timepicker({
                                        'minTime': '2:00pm',
                                        'maxTime': '6:30pm',
                                        'showDuration': false
                                    });
                                });
                            </script>
                            <pre class="code" data-language="javascript"></pre>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFoOL.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
I Hope Below code solves your problem perfectly    

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $( function() {
      $( "#durationExample" ).timepicker({interval: 60, minTime: '2',maxTime: '6:00pm','showDuration': true});
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-3">
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="appt-time">Choose an appointment time: </label>
                    <input id="durationExample" type="text" class="time" />
                </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```